# Trying to export sf dataframe to .csv file in R with st_write

Tags: r, csv, geometry, export-to-csv, r-sf

I have a sf dataframe which has geometry column looking like this:

```
geometry
  list(list(c(53252.151421, 421516.3252...
  list(list(c(53252.151421, 421516.3252...
  list(list(c(53252.151421, 421516.3252...
```

and I'm trying to export this whole df to .csv using this command:

```
st_write(df, "name.csv", layer_options = "GEOMETRY=AS_WKT")
```

However, after running the command I get this csv file.

[this is the exported .csv after running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o33ZF.jpg)

how can I fix this?

Comment: If you are exporting the geometry as WKT, you can append the WKT as a column. Then remove the geometry column. Then any `write.csv()` or equivalent will work.

Comment: alternativley, if you want the coordinates in a 'long' table, you can `sfheaders::sf_to_df(sf, keep = T)` to convert it into a data.frame, then `write.csv()`

Comment: If your `geometry` column consists of entries that are lists of lists, you are probably doing something very strange.

Comment: @jmw - a list of list is the standard structure of Polygons.